# SQL JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I've been having trouble understanding this example, I have the answer but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how this works.  How are the joins working exactly?

Examine the structures of the PLAYER and TEAM tables:

```
    PLAYER
    -------------
    PLAYER_ID NUMBER(9) PK
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25)
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25)
    TEAM_ID NUMBER
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(9)

    TEAM
    ----------
    TEAM_ID NUMBER PK
    TEAM_NAME VARCHAR2(30)
```

For this example, team managers are also players, and the `MANAGER_ID` column references the `PLAYER_ID` column. For players who are managers, `MANAGER_ID` is `NULL`.

Which `SELECT` statement will provide a list of all players, including the player's name, the team name, and the player's manager's name?

ANSWER:

```
    SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name, m.last_name, m.first_name, t.team_name
    FROM player p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN player m ON (p.manager_id = m.player_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN team t ON (p.team_id = t.team_id);
```

Comment: The best way to illustrate this is to literally draw a picture of your tables.  The one on the left, and the one on the right.  Which way is the arrow pointing?  That's the way your join will work.  You will either get "all the records from the left", or "all the records from the right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first `LEFT OUTER JOIN` takes the player table, then adds on the info for each players manager. Each player has an `ID` for its manager, who is also a player with an `ID`. If Mr. A, with `player_id 9`, is a manager for Ted, with `player_id 5`, then Ted's manager_id will be `9`. The first join takes Ted's `manager_id`, `9`, and matches it to the `player_id` of his manager, Mr. A, so that the manager's info is now on the table as well, and `m.last_name` and `m.first_name` will show Mr. A's name. The second join takes the `team_id` and simply matches it to the table of teams, appending the `team_name` to the player's information in the table.

It's tough to explain without sample data and diagrams. Sorry.

Comment: I kind of get this actually.  Going to go through it a few more times and I think I will understand how this is working. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your example the players that are also managers, have a null value in the manager_id column.  Take the first part of the SQL statement, which is:

```
SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name, m.last_name, m.first_name, t.team_name
FROM player p
LEFT OUTER JOIN player m ON (p.manager_id = m.player_id)
```

Since you are performing a LEFT JOIN (instead of an INNER JOIN), your manager records will not be filtered out (even though their NULL value in the manager_id column, will not successfully join to any player_id in the player table), and m.last_name and m.first_name will be NULL for those manager players.

If you were to change that query to an INNER JOIN instead, your players that are also managers would not be returned at all by the query, because they have a NULL value for manager_id and there is no player records with a player_id of NULL.

```
SELECT p.last_name, p.first_name, m.last_name, m.first_name, t.team_name
FROM player p
INNER JOIN player m ON (p.manager_id = m.player_id)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ah I see. The inner join would just return all the players without the managers.  The LEFT OUTER will return all the players and the managers.

Comment: You got it!  It is hard to visualize at first, I really struggled with that concept for the longest time.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to think about it is to look at each of the `joins` individually.

A `Left Outer Join` is a type of `Join` that joins two tables together on the provided pairings, and if a match exists, data is pulled from the right-hand side.  But if no match is found, the data returned from the right is simply `Null`.  This is different from an `Inner Join` where if no match is found, the records are simply omitted.

For this, a player may or may not have a manager, so it's using a `Left Outer Join` to either pull back the manager's `Player` record if the player has a manager, or if the player does not, it will return `Null`.

Similarly, a player may or may not be on a team, so it is `Left Outer Join`ing to the `Team` table to pull back the `Team` information if the player is on a team, otherwise it will be `Null`.

The `Select` statement simply chooses which fields it wants to display from the three tables.

A good example of the different types of `Join`s can be seen here:[Difference Between Inner and Outer Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)